# Shopify Graphql API

Tags: shopify-api

"I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find Shopify GraphQL API for creating orders. Shopify provides REST Admin API for creating orders, but I couldn't find a GraphQL API for creating orders directly. Is it true that GraphQL API does not provide an option for direct order creation? If it is true, then how can we create orders using the GraphQL API?". The REST API allows us to directly create orders. Is it correct that the GraphqL implementation requires us to first call the draftOrderCreate mutation and then the draftOrderComplete?

"I am using the Shopify REST Admin API to create orders in my Shopify store. The orders I am creating are based on my CSV file. Due to Shopify's rate limits, I can only create 4 orders in a single request, and to create more, I would need to upgrade my plan. I noticed that the GraphQL API provides a higher limit of 50 points/second, so I considered using the GraphQL API for order creation. However, I couldn't find a direct GraphQL API endpoint for creating orders. It seems that I need to create a draft order first and proceed from there."